# Get Send Job's name in Tracking Extracts file

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, tracking-extract, jobid

We receive the **JobID** value in the `SendJobs.csv` file in our tracking extracts (generated using a *Data Extract* activity in *Automation Studio*).

But is it possible to get the name of the Send (not Email) in our file as well? The value I am looking for is the one appearing in Email Studio's Send tracking under the *Name* column with a hyperlink. This name is apparently not the Email name used, but a name specific to the send.

[image]

Comment: I believe the only time that Name would be different from the name of the email is if you use a 'User-Initiated Send' (mostly used in automation studio) or Triggered Send Definition (use via API or Journey Builder).

Comment: @Gortonington I see. But is it possible to get that name in Tracking Extracts?

Comment: Those would be the columns 'SendDefinitionExternalKey' (UI Sends) and 'TriggeredSendExternalKey' (Triggers) inside the SendJobs.csv file. But I just had a few people tell me that the 'Name' there should always be email name. I checked and verified that UI sends do not seem to change name from email.  Have you checked to see if the name of the email changed between send and current date? Original name at schedule would be used for Tracking.

Comment: The client uses UI Sends and usually gives them a new name. But I see now that, that is not the name appearing in the Send Tracking as Name. So, are you suggesting that they are the same value? A bit confused here.

Comment: So email name should be the only thing inside of 'Name' in 'My Tracking'.  The only way this would be different from current emails is if you changed the name of the email after the send already went out. Than that send would have the old name that the email had at time of send.

Comment: I think you are right. And I think what the client had in mind was to have the name of the UI send show up on tracking files instead of the email name. And I doubt if that is possible. Thank you as always. You can post it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email name should be the only value inside of 'Name' in 'My Tracking' inside the SFMC UI.

The only way this name would be different from current emails is if you changed the name of the email after the send already went out. Than that send would have the old name that the email had at time of send.

That being said, you should be able to match 1:1 from the Data Extract to the SFMC UI my tracking page via emailname = name.

Comment: Thank you for your reply again. I am now querying the **_Job** data view for more detailed information. Somebody suggested that the UI name I'm looking for is the `EmailSendDefinition` inside this data view. But I only get numbers that look like ID in it.