# Using SendLog to retrieve User-Initiated Send name for each Job Id

Tags: marketing-cloud, logging, email-tracking

After realizing that it is not possible to receive the name of the User-Initiated Send in the *Data Extract* activity of *Automation Studio*, we contacted Salesforce for a workaround. Our client, in addition to the name of the email in the tracking extract files, would like to have the name of User-Initiated Send. Of course, not all sends are done using User-Initiated Sends, and in this case, we can have an empty value.

Unfortunately, I could not gather a lot from Salesforce support's answer. Text from the help pages where copy-pasted with no directions. But they seemed to recommend that I create **Send Logs** to this end. They have now activated this feature in our Business Unit.

I have followed [this help page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333925&type=1&mode=1) to create a *SendLog* DE. But I do not know what extra fields I should create to accommodate the name of the UI Send and how they should look.

[On the Send Logging](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_logging.htm&type=5) help page, there are mentionings of using *Query Activities* and *AMPScript* (!) but no mentioning of how the Query Activity is supposed to populate the name of the UI send in my SendLog DE and what does AMPScript have to do with any of this.

So receiving one extra variable of UI Send name in our `SendJob.csv` file has become a twisted issue.

Comment: Is hard coding the User-Initiated Send's name on each email a feasible solution? Because there is a way to populate this data on Send Logs if you set it up on your emails. Let me know if this is something that could be accepted by your client and I'll provide more information..

Comment: @RachidMamai They would like to analyze data based on each send and not necessarily the name of the email. To this end, they add some extra data about that specific send in the name of UI Send. This name is not available in the tracking extracts. So if we give the email some extra information, we can still cannot recognize which is which when we use it for two different sends to two different groups of recipients. All we have is a Job Id which does not have a textual representation. So we would like to take advantage of User-Initiated send name as that extra layer.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get this from the data extract (Tracking Extract) of 'SendJobs'.

Inside that file there is a column named 'SendDefinitionExternalKey'. The values in there are the external keys of the User-Initiated Sends you have used. You can then connect this to individual sends by linking via JobID (SendID) to the 'Sends' file.

[image]

If you need to explicitly have the name and the ExternalKey is not good enough, then you would need to utilize some [API calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/emailsenddefinition.htm) to gather the names that match the keys.

---

**EDIT**

I think I found another way. Albeit, it relies on a Discover report, which has its own drawbacks - BUT it removes the need for the data extract and custom development to draw the name from the API Object.

What you would do is build a 'Blank Template for Email Sending Performance' report in the Reports App.

[image]

Once you are in there, you just need to select 'Send Definition' and 'Message Type' along with whatever other fields you want.

**Send Definition** - Will provide the name of the User-Initiated or Triggered Send Definition used for the send.
**Message Type** - Used to show if it is a 'Triggered Send' or 'Send Definition Send' (aka User-Initiated Send). The third option is 'Job Send' which is basically via the Send Wizard/UI send.

[image]

You can then save this to the FTP, import into a DE and then use for any SQL queries you need.

Comment: Yes, I think we had the same discussion in another question of mine: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291241/get-send-jobs-name-in-tracking-extracts-file you are right in that 'SendDefinitionExternalKey' could be the id of the UI Send, but how to connect it to the list of the UI send to retrieve the name is probably not doable via Query Activities of Automation studio, is that correct? Do I need to use the API to that aim?

Comment: Yes, to get the name, not the key, you need to utilize the API unless you manually store it somewhere (e.g. grab name/key via API in script activity and store in DE for reference in query).

Comment: You could also name your External Key of the UI the same as the name when creating them as well. This would remove the need to do any other matching.

Comment: @Disasterkid - OK. I think I found your best bet without custom Development incorporating the API.  You can use the Discover 'Blank Template for Email Sending Performance' report.  Inside this you build it from scratch and the field 'Send Definition' will provide the name of the User-Initiated Send or Triggered Send Definition name.  To differentiate these, you can add in 'Message Type' to show if it is 'Triggered Send' or 'Send Definition Send' (aka User-Initiated).  I will edit my answer to add this in.

Comment: I'm so looking forward to trying this out. The "Blank Template for Email Sending Performance" is not available for this account. So I should probably ask SF to fix this. I will get back to this as soon as I get access.

Comment: So, this is what I got from Salesforce: "Unfortunately, as your account is Pro Edition which does not include Discover, please kindly reach out to your Account Executive to add an order before this can be enabled for you." I'm sorry that I cannot test your detailed description. Let me know if there are alternatives.

Comment: Is it possible to download a list of all User-Initiated sends via the API?

Comment: The SOAP API object I linked to in my answer should do that for you.